# How to disable the droplet/beep sound of the lateral volume buttons on Samsung Galaxy A3?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, audio

I have a Galaxy A3 with Android 5.0.2 and when I press the sound buttons in order to turn the volume up or down, those buttons make a beep/droplet sound. How can I disable this sound?

I know it was possible on previous devices, as I have a Galaxy Note 10.1 tablet, where these annoying beeps are disabled.

Is there a way to do that in perhaps in `Settings` or with the installation of a third party app?